# How to parse SVN log?

Tags: bash, svn, sed, awk

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
rXXX | user1 | 2013-07-02 00:18:02 +0400 (Tue, 02 Jul 2013) | 1 line

commit1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
rYYY | user2 | 2013-07-01 18:24:44 +0400 (Mon, 01 Jul 2013) | 1 line

commit2
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is a `svn log -l 2 index.php` output and I see **XXX** as latest revision and **YYY** as previous.
Question: how can I fetch **YYY** revision from this output? In result I want to:

`svn log -l 2 index.php | awk {'svn up -r $1 $2'}`

(Update file $2 to previous revision $1)

And in total result I want to make an alias like a `svn prev FILENAME`

Answer (score 0):

`svn log -l 2` will produce just the last 2 revisions, so you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

rev=( $(svn log -l 2 index.php | awk '/^r[0-9]+/ {sub(/r/,"",$1); print $1}') )
svn up -r ${rev[1]} ${rev[0]}
```

I'd make this a function, though, not an alias.